# Ext-JS and AMFPHP - getting Malformed Amf Packet error

Tags: extjs, amfphp

I have a very basic connection test setup, which works when I use the JSON ccontentType but fails when I leave it as default and request just the byte data. I assume this must be an error or problem with the AMFPHP config or server and not necessarily the Ext-JS which is why I'm primarily tagging this as AMFPHP. Any clues would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My params array:

var amf_params = {
            serviceName: 'svcp'
        ,   methodName: 'fetchp'
        ,   parameters: []
    };

**WORKS, returns data set in JSON:**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST'
        ,   url: 'http://mysite.com/Amfphp/?contentType=application/json'
        ,   binary: true
        ,   params: JSON.stringify(amf_params)
        ,   success: function(response) {
            console.log('response as string: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
});
```

Response in console:

> [{"id":1,"TID":1,"updatedt":"2012-11-24 23:35:43","createdt":"2012-11-24 23:35:43","firstname":"Bob"  .... etc.

**DOES NOT WORK, returns an error "Malformed Amf Packet, connection may have dropped"**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST'
        ,   url: 'http://mysite.com/Amfphp/'
        ,   binary: true
        ,   params: JSON.stringify(amf_params)
        ,   success: function(response) {
                console.log('response as string: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log('responseText: ' + response.responseText);
        }
});
```

Response in console (yes with the funky characters - not intending to bold anything below just didnt want to edit the text):

`������/1/onStatus�null��C� faultCode����������faultString�1Malformed Amf Packet, connection may have dropped�faultDetail�#0 /home/public_html/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Deserializer.php(75): Amfphp_Core_Amf_Deserializer->readHeaders()

## 1 /home/public_html/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Handler.php(92): Amfphp_Core_Amf_Deserializer->deserialize()

## 2 /home/public_html/Amfphp/Core/Gateway.php(187): Amfphp_Core_Amf_Handler->deserialize(Array, Array, '{"serviceName":...')

## 3 /home/public_html/Amfphp/index.php(34): Amfphp_Core_Gateway->service()

## 4 {main}�  rootCause�Amfphp_Core_Exception��   ��  `

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is AMF, which is the default format for an answer. 
This means that the Json plugin is not kicking in, either because it's not there or you're messing up the call somehow. 
Do the Javascript examples work? If so, try to use a packet sniffer to compare what happens with your code compared to what happens when it works.
If not, post back here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ariel. AMF is what I want, and I left the contentType off because I do not want JSON. So not sure what you mean by the Json plugin not kicking in. Which Javascript examples?

Comment: Hi again, Ariel. Still can't quite figure this out. My AMFPHP service browser works great. Its AMFPHP 2.0, the latest version of ext-js pulled from http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js, and just using the examples found here: http://www.silexlabs.org/132517/the-blog/sencha-touch-2-and-amfphp2/   the JSON works but the AMF doesn't. I will try the packet sniffer now but not quite sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: The thing is, if you want to get AMF, you must send AMF. AmfPHP assumes that you want the same protocol for the request and response. Why do you want AMF if you're using Javascript? Are you using an AMF lib for Javascript?

Comment: Thank you again for all your replies.... Ahh - that makes sense that I need to send AMF to get AMF. How do I do that in JS? Is there a built in function in extjs? You can see right now I'm using JSON.stringify() to create a json string of my JS params.  ---- The reason I'm wanting AMF is that the app I'm building will have many many asynchronous requests and I need to reduce the round trip time as much as I can. ---- Ext-Js has that "binary: true" property in its Ajax.request, and from what I've read its ready for AMF.

Comment: there are a few Javascript implementations of AMF around, I can't vouch for their quality though, you'll have to try. Have a look here, you'll see a few more links in the comments http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/07/amf-js-a-pure-javascript-amf-implementation/